# Proxyquire and Sinon to check if function is called

Tags: javascript, node.js, sinon, spy, proxyquire

I'm trying to write a test within a file called `fooTest` that's trying to check if, in the file `foo`, when I call `fooHandler`, a function in the file `bar` is called.

I've been able to test that the function in `bar` is called. (`barSpy = sinon.spy()`, and then adding the path and the spy as a stub to Proxyquire) However, an existing test is now breaking -- the existing test checks the output on a function that uses `bar`, but I think the `spying` is messing with the behavior. How can I address this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please [create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)